# Node will not persist to Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a Role node that contains some privileges that I am trying to persist into Neo4j.  When I construct the object, I see that the privileges exist, but after the save call they disappear.

Here's my Role Node:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Role {

    @GraphId Long id;
    private RoleType roleType;

    //@RelatedToVia(type="HAS_ROLE", direction=Direction.OUTGOING)
    private List<Person> users;

    private List<Privilege> defaultPrivileges;
    //private List<Task> tasks;


    public Role(){}

    public Role(RoleType roleType){
        this.roleType=roleType;
        this.defaultPrivileges=roleType.getDefaultPrivileges();
    }

}
```

Here's my save:

```
admin= roleRepository.save(admin);
```

Before I save the object it is fully populate and after it's empty.  Any ideas as to why that might be

EDIT:
The code causing the issue is in my Privilege class.

This does not work:

```
public class Privilege {

    private String name;

    public Privilege(PrivilegeType pt) {
        this.name = pt.name();
    }
}
```

This works:

```
 public class Privilege {

    private String name;

    public Privilege(String pt) {
        this.name = pt;
    }
}
```

Why would that be causing it to not persist?  What am I missing in my RoleRepository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reloads the entity after storing it, and by default it only loads a shallow copy of related information.

you can use `template.fetch(role.users)` or `template.fetch(role.tasks)`
or add @Fetch to the tasks list for instance.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue.